# Using Excel 2010 with Visual FOXPRO

Tags: database, excel, visual-foxpro

I've been asked to create a kind of translator through Excel 2010 and Visual FOXPRO, But I don't know Visual FP, Someone can explains me how to connect them?
I'm using WIN10, Office 2010.

Comment: You'll have to explain what exactly you need more. Are you needing to export data from Foxpro to Excel or Excel to Foxpro? What do you mean by translator?

Comment: I need to read/write data in this vpf database from an excel vba application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions doesn't really explain what you need.

If you don't know VFP, how would you connect using VFP? Still are you asking sample code to connect to Excel and do some stuff? If so you don't only need to know VFP, but Excel VBA as well. Excel use VBA for its own processing. Below is a very simple VFP code. Check the comments for what it does (the code within the with ... endwith block is Excel VBA).

```
* Select sample data and copy to clipboard as TAB delimited
Select * From (_Samples+'data\customer') ;
    Into Cursor crsMyData ;
    nofilter
Local lcTemp
lcTemp = ForcePath(Sys(2015)+'.tmp', Sys(2023))
Copy To (m.lcTemp) Type Delimited With "" With Tab
_Cliptext = Filetostr(m.lcTemp)
Erase (m.lcTemp)
* Select sample data and copy to clipboard as TAB delimited


* Create Excel Workbook
* and paste the data copied above
* starting at A3
* and autofit columns
oExcel = Createobject('Excel.Application')
With oExcel
  .Workbooks.Add()
  .Activeworkbook.Activesheet.Range('A3').PasteSpecial()
  .Selection.Name = 'myData'
  .Range('A1').Activate()
  .Range('myData').Columns.Autofit()
  .Visible = .T.
Endwith
```

Comment: I need to read/write data in this vpf database from an excel vba application

Comment: You can use VFPOLEDB to read/write VFP tables from Excel. You don't need to know VFP for that. But beware you can't use 64 bits Excel to do that. One easy way would be to add a datasource (QueryTables.Add method - I don't know the exact location via menus).